# collision detection fabrics js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js, i use the following function to put an image on canvas, when i click on canvas an image is put on that location, i want to know if there is way that i can check weather there is something already present at location where i am clicking  especially if there is another image or not

```
  document.getElementById("door").onclick = function () {

            canvas.on('mouse:down', function (o) {
                fabric.Image.fromURL('http://localhost:60099/Images/door.png', function (img) {
                    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

                    logo = img.set({ left: pointer.x , top: pointer.y  })

                    canvas.add(logo);
                    canvas.item(objC).lockMovementY = true;
                    canvas.item(objC).lockMovementX = true;
                    canvas.renderAll();

                });

            });

        }
```

Comment: can you share your fiddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Collisions can be detected with the fabric.js 'intersectsWithObject' function. Consider their 'intersection' example:

http://fabricjs.com/intersection

Comment: This is useful, however it's only rudimentary collision detection based on bounding box. `"Note that intersection is checked against bounding boxes, not actual shapes"`. e.g. A collision won't occur along the curved edge of a circle, as most ppl would desire.