# Fabric JS & proper collision detection

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using the current version of Fabric JS (1.7.13) and I want some proper collision detection.

The Fabric JS website has this page: http://fabricjs.com/intersection

And there is a note at the top of the page:

> Note that intersection is checked against bounding boxes, not actual
>   shapes

I am after a solution that does collision detection on the actual shapes.

Does such a solution exist?

---

I have found some similar questions here, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258284/collision-detection-fabrics-js), but all of the ones I have found only do collision detection on the bounding boxes, not on the shapes themselves.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591927/snap-edges-of-objects-to-each-other-and-prevent-overlap

Comment: unfortunately not - I just tested it by changing the boxes to circles - the snapping is still performed on the bounding boxes and not the shapes themselves

Comment: @Jimmery, it is possible if you will use clipping libraries like jsclipper, but I am not sure how performance vise will work this on mouse move event. It is  all dependence how many shapes do you have, what shape types do you have, and what is your canvas size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code pen can help you- https://codepen.io/qbahamutp/pen/EPJmzj

```js
/*
 canvas dimension settings, using asset: 
  seiyria's bootstrap-slider
  https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider
*/
var AdjustCanvasDimensions = function() {
 window.canvas.setHeight(iHeight.getValue());
 window.canvas.setWidth(iWidth.getValue());
 window.canvas.renderAll();

 
 
 $('label[for="canvas-width"]').text( iWidth.getValue() + 'cm' );
 $('label[for="canvas-height"]').text( iHeight.getValue() + 'cm' );
 console.log( 'Height:' + iHeight.getValue() );
// console.log( 'Width:' + iWidth.getValue() );
}


var iWidth = $('#canvas-width').slider().on('slide', AdjustCanvasDimensions).data('slider');

var iHeight= $("#canvas-height").slider({
// reversed : true
}).on('slide', AdjustCanvasDimensions).data('slider');


/*
 canvas setup using asset: 
  fabricjs
  https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/
*/
window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabriccanvas');
window.counter = 0;
var newleft = 0;
var edgedetection = 20; //pixels to snap

canvas.selection = false;

function plusrect(top, left, width, height, fill) {
    window.canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        top: 100,
        name: 'rectangle ' + window.counter,
        left: 0 + newleft,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: 'rgba(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ', 0.75)',
        lockRotation: true,
    lockScalingX: true,
    lockScalingY: true,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        cornerSize: 15,
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        perPixelTargetFind: true,
    }));
    window.counter++;
    newleft += 200;
}
this.canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
    obj.setCoords(); //Sets corner position coordinates based on current angle, width and height
    canvas.forEachObject(function (targ) {
        activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

        if (targ === activeObject) return;


        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.tr.x - targ.oCoords.tl.x) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.left = targ.left - activeObject.width;
        }
        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.tl.x - targ.oCoords.tr.x) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.left = targ.left + targ.width;
        }
        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.br.y - targ.oCoords.tr.y) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.top = targ.top - activeObject.height;
        }
        if (Math.abs(targ.oCoords.br.y - activeObject.oCoords.tr.y) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.top = targ.top + targ.height;
        }
        if (activeObject.intersectsWithObject(targ) && targ.intersectsWithObject(activeObject)) {
            targ.strokeWidth = 10;
            targ.stroke = 'red';
        } else {
            targ.strokeWidth = 0;
            targ.stroke = false;
        }
        if (!activeObject.intersectsWithObject(targ)) {
            activeObject.strokeWidth = 0;
            activeObject.stroke = false;
        }
    });
});

$('#pushit').on('click', function(){
 plusrect()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<div id="start" class="container">
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Canvas eigenschappen</legend>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
   <label for="canvas-width">Breedte</label>
   <input id="canvas-width" name="canvas-width" data-slider-id='canvas-width' type="text" data-slider-min="100" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="500" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2 text-right">
   <label for="canvas-height">Hoogte</label>
   <input id="canvas-height" name="canvas-height" data-slider-id='canvas-height' type="text" data-slider-min="100" data-slider-max="400" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="200" data-slider-orientation="vertical"  />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 canvaswrapper">

   <canvas id="fabriccanvas" width="500" height="200" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-10">
   <button type="button" id="pushit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Object toevoegen </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```